# How to read Top Margin of the DIV

Tags: javascript, css, margin

Here is my code

```
<script>
function showin(box) {

       cur = parseInt(document.getElementById(box).style.marginTop);
       alert(cur);
    }
 showin('child');

</script>

<div id="parent" class="parent">
    <div id="child" class="child" style="margin-top:-10px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

why it's not giving me any alert message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't working because you are invoking it before the DOM is ready and the margin can be calculated.

You should instead do:

```
function showin(box) {
   cur = parseInt(document.getElementById(box).style.marginTop);
   alert(cur);
}
window.onload = function() { 
   showin('child'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the function before the DOM has been created,

if you're using jquery try wrapping the showin('child'); in a document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  showin('child');
});
```

This will wait till everything is created

EDIT: or use window.onload :)

Comment: While this is correct, do note that the OP has not specified that he is using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script>
    function showin(box) {
        cur = parseInt(document.getElementById(box).style.marginTop);
        alert(cur);
    }
    window.onload = function(){
        showin('child');
    }
</script>

<div id="parent" class="parent">
    <div id="child" class="child" style="margin-top:-10px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Since you are trying to run your showin javascript function above the HTML, at the point the javascript is ran, the div#child is not rendered yet.

You have to look and understand [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload)

Answer (score 0):

That's because your script executes before your window is ready and does not get the element that you've passed and throws an error. This error causes break in execution and javascript breaks. please google for Jquery's $(document).ready method to know more